# Can an 802.11AC router become an 802.11AD router?

Tags: wireless-router, 802.11, 802.11ac

I recently came across an [advertisement](https://www.androidcentral.com/best-wifi-6-routers) for an asus 802.11AX router and I wanted to see if its possible to upgrade a router to AX being that they share the same frequencies. Whats stopping a company from upgrading the CFE on the router and the router firmware to run on 802.11AX?

Especially since 802.11AX runs on all channels between [1-7GHZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ax) when available and the current offerings still use 2.4ghz and 5ghz channels.

Could someone write custom code for something like openwrt to make AC routers work on the new AX protocol?

Comment: Not possible - requires new hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there's just not enough detail known about how 802.11ac routers work internally. Very likely they do SDR on some special purpose DSPs (which are different from the main CPU, for which details are known, so people can write things like OpenWRT) to decode 802.11ac.

So if you can pick a specific 802.11ac router and provide enough detail that anyone could actually understand, access and change the DSP firmware, the open source community would be very very grateful to you (and you could do a lot of interesting things with that besides 802.ad).

As for "what's stopping companies to do that", there may be monetary reasons (they want you to buy new routers), as well as other reasons (they don't want people to find out how to update firmware on the DSPs; the DSPs may not be powerful enough for other encoding schemes, etc.)